# Is it required or allowed to make a שהחיינו on a highly seasonal variety of apple?

Tags: halacha, fruits, shehecheyanu

We live in a city with good shops and the majority of fruits and vegetables are available all the year round. For this reason, following Rabbinic advice, I do not make a שהחיינו on fruits. There is one variety of apple, [the Egremont Russet,](https://www.orangepippin.com/apples/egremont-russet) which has a distinctive skin appearance and nutty flavour which I value and is only available in the shops for a short period (around now).

Are there sources that deal with the question of whether it is required or allowed to make a  שהחיינו on such a seasonal variety of apple?

Comment: Meaning, is שהחינו on the particular species or on the class? (Genus? I can never keep track of the taxonomic terms.)

Comment: @DonielF No, almost certainly these are just different cultivars in the same species.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this before, but know that shehechiyanu on a new fruit is always a reshut, never a chiyuv (eruvin 40b). So _allowed_ is all you can really ask about.

Answer (score 3):

The sources are all found surrounding Shulchan Arukh OC 225:4 discussing two kinds of cherries (?) (sweet and sour?). Both the Shulchan Arukh and Rama rule that your case seemingly would get its own Shehechiyanu, but many later authorities argued. CYLOR as modern opinions vary.