# Are two different color apples valid Mishloach Manos?

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot

Are two different color apples considered to be different minim for the purposes of Mishloach Manos? They do taste [different](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mishloach_Manot#What.E2.80.99s_called_two_portions.3F) from each other.

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86853/759

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch uses the phrase שתי מנות בשר https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.695.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en which might point to 2 servings of the generically same food.

Comment: Good luck finding a halachik source saying you can't send two of the same food.

Comment: Two brachos is made up,two different tastes has a source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so clear if one needs 2 separate items. However, the gemara in megila 7a seems to imply that two different items should be used. This is how the Aruch Hashulchan (695:14) seems to hold. So if you send a dark piece of meat and a white piece of meat those are considered two separate  manos since they taste different. Rav Eliyashiv (Ashrei Ha’Ish pg 311:5)
holds that two different drinks counts as two manos. So it seems according to this two different apples would count as two separate manos, especially if they taste different. 
Rav Eliyashiv also held that two big pieces of the same thing may be considered two separate manos. However, he held that one should be machmir and use different items,or at least two separate parts of a chicken.

Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky in Kovetz Halachos 17:2 holds that one should not use two of the same thing, based off the Aruch Hashulchan 695:14. See also Eshel Avraham (Butschach) 695.

Text of Ashrei HaIsh:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rav Shmuel Kamentesky in Kovetz Halachos 17:4 brings this exact question whether a red and green apple which have different tastes are considered two manos. He holds that it is considered one min and one would need an additional item. He also holds that red wine and white wine are also considered one min. However, see my other answer.